# Can you "swap" slices of C++ std vectors?

Tags: c++, stdvector

If I have two C++ vectors:

```
vector<int> a(5) {1,2,3,4,5};
vector<int> b(5) {6,7,8,9,10};
```

is there a one-line way to use the swap method to swap slices of a and b?  Something like

```
swap(a[something ... something], b[something ... something]);
```

giving, for instance

`a` equal to `{1,9,10,4,5}` and `b` equal to `{6,7,8,2,3}`?

Comment: Are the slices guaranteed to be the same size?

Comment: @YiminRong   That was the application I was looking at.  I would be happy to hear if that can be generalized, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[std::swap_ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges).

```
std::swap_ranges(a.begin()+1, a.begin()+3, b.begin()+3);
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5PEnKnMra)

Comment: Learn something new every day!  Thanks!